# How to send a text message with a link to my app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, deep-linking

I am building a React Native app with the Expo managed workflow. I want users to be able to get a free month of the premium version if they get someone to sign up. I want the user to be able to type in their friend's phone number and then automatically send their friend a text with a link to my app. I already have it set up to send the text message. Now I am trying to figure out how to make the text message include a link that opens the app if they have it on their phone already or sends them to the app store or play store depending on their phone. I've read a lot about this and tried several different methods but can't figure out how to do it. Does anyone know an easy way to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Share](https://reactnative.dev/docs/share) from react-native

```
import { Share } from 'react-native';
//...
<Button
     title="share"
     onPress={() => Share.share({
         message:
             `Your message. ${yourAppUrl}`,
     })}
/>
```

See also [expo-linking](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/linking/)

```
import * as Linking from 'expo-linking';
Linking.openURL('https://appurl');
```